# Запуск дочерних потоков из django

Tags: python, потоки-данных, django

Задача состоит в следующем: пользователь запускаем процесс создания некоторого набора объектов, который может занять неопределенное количество времени, гораздо большее чем HTTP-таймаут. Для этого планируется использовать потоки или отдельные процессы. В то же самое время пользователь на странице видит степень выполнения процесса. Вопрос следующий: каким образом данная задача наилучшим образом выполняется в Django. Как это вообще реализовать с учетом того, что это веб-сайт? Извините если вопрос не совсем понятен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуйте, например, celery

Comment: А в чем проблема прост запускать потоки из обработчика запроса? Почему все рекомендуют именно django-celery?

Comment: если вкратце, то больше фич, если надо подробностей, то вот, например: http://habrahabr.ru/company/biggo/blog/102742/